# How to group by and calculate sum and select where is less than given amount in SQL Server / C# Linq

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

How to group by year and calculate the sum, select where `TotalCollected` is less than given amount in SQL Server or C# Linq.

I want to group data by `Year` and `Refno`, calculate the sum and select Where the sum result is less than -100000.

My current code look like this in SQL Server

```
SELECT 
    Year, Refno, SetaCode,
    SUM(TotalCollected) AS TotalCollected
FROM 
    transactions 
GROUP BY 
    Year, Refno, TypeCode  
ORDER BY
    Year, Refno, TypeCode;
```

The current output is like this:

```
   | Year | Refno     | TypeCode  | TotalCollected |
   +------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
   | 2015 | G30714630 | 16        | -534713,04     |
   | 2015 | G30738332 | 16        | -16471         |
   | 2015 | G00746893 | 11        | -441770,75     |
   | 2015 | G10712596 | 11        | -1254,53       |
   | 2015 | G30711221 | 21        | -740616,41     |
   | 2015 | G50769901 | 21        | -1131          |
   | 2014 | G30714630 | 16        | -26575,4       |
   | 2014 | G10703033 | 11        | -122156,62     |
   | 2013 | G00750516 | 21        | -31578,38      |
   | 2013 | G30775855 | 21        | -9032,19       |
   | 2013 | G50749525 | 21        | 0              |
   | 2013 | G30714630 | 16        | -0,4           |
   | 2013 | G10703033 | 11        | 527,17         |
   +------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
```

Any help please even if you can reply with C# linq query code it fine.

Please help me guys I am stuck.

Comment: `having sum(TotalCollected) < -100000` after the `group by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you it working. But it showing even those which `TotalCollected  >=0` how can I exclude those ones?

Comment: @Dlamini.M that's not possible with that `having` condition. What you mean?

Comment: @krtek ok I get you. But what I believe is that nothing impossible in programming but problem is the logic. I think they is another way of doing it if it not possible with `having` condition.

Comment: @Dlamini.M The question is what do you mean by "it working" and then "but showing blah-blah", i.e "not working". Gordon Linoff comment does answer your original question, so if it doesn't provide you the desired result, then update your question.

Answer (score 1):

Linq version:

```
var result = transactions
    .GroupBy(t => new { t.Year, t.Refno, t.SetaCode })
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Year = grp.Key.Year,
        Refno = grp.Key.Refno,
        SetaCode = grp.Key.SetaCode,
        TotalCollected = grp.Sum(x => x.TotalCollected)
    })
    .Where(r => r.TotalCollected < -100000)
    .OrderBy(r => r.Year).ThenBy(r => r.Refno).ThenBy(r => r.SetaCode)
    .ToList();
```